# Trying to get XML from an URL

Tags: android, xml, url, xmlpullparser

Previously, I used the the XML file from the assets folder. The app can read it very well. The next step I want put this XML on the web server. But at this stage, the app cannot recognize any data. It confused me couple of days.

```
AssetManager asset = getAssets();
InputStream input = asset.open("student.xml");
List<Student> list = ParserByPULL.getStudents(input);
```

Everything works fine if the file in assets folder.
Then I tried to get it from an URL.

```
String path = "http://fthgyj.tup632.cnaaa11.com/student.xml";
URL url = new URL(path);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
InputStream input = url.openConnection().getInputStream(); 
List<Student> list = ParserByPULL.getStudents(input);
```

I have added the permission of connecting the INTERNET at manifest file.
Does anyone has an idea about this?

Comment: So what's going wrong then? Do you get exception or what, just empty response?

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException perhaps?

Comment: tell us exact symptoms of your problem. Making us guess is not nice and besides you won't get your answer

Comment: I am sorry. Nothing shows on screen. But the app can run as normal(No error on the logcat).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call

```
conn.connect();
InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
```

And then check if you got the xml fetched:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    builder.append(line);
}
reader.close();
Log.d("tag", "output: " + builder.toString());
```

Comment: I tried it, but still not working. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: And are you sure that you dont get anything from the input stream? Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this to Pull and Parse the XML file from URL,

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/11/boost-android-xml-parsing-xml-pull.html

Comment: Thank you, I will read it line by line.

Comment: Did you find this Useful?